# NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'The Live Photo type cannot be specified without the Image media type'

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm trying to fetch only Live Photos from my gallery for processing tasks. However, the below code gives a runtime crash:

```
        let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
        imagePicker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
        //imagePicker.mediaTypes = [kUTTypeImage, kUTTypeLivePhoto] as [String]
        imagePicker.mediaTypes = [kUTTypeLivePhoto] as [String]
        imagePicker.delegate = self
        present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Error: NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'The Live Photo type cannot be specified without the Image media type'

Coincidentally, using **PHPhotosPicker** with **SwiftUI (iOS 16+)** successfully **fetches** live photos only:

```
PhotosPicker(selection: $viewModel.imageSelection,
                             matching: .livePhotos,
                             photoLibrary: .shared())

So, curious to know what's wrong with the former code?
```

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimagepickercontroller) for `UIImagePickerController` states:

> To obtain the full motion and sound content when the user chooses a Live Photo with the image picker, you *must* include both the kUTTypeImage and kUTTypeLivePhoto types in the mediaTypes array.

But more importantly, the `.photoLibrary` source type was deprecated in iOS 14.0. The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimagepickercontroller/sourcetype/photolibrary) states:

> Deprecated
> Use PHPickerViewController instead.

Only use `UIImagePickerController` to take photos with the camera. For selecting existing media, use `PHPickerViewController`. It has many more useful features. And it supports what you want in this case.